# Is there a historic origin for final ending (cadence) of V-I with melody tones ^3 ^1 in some jazz standards?

Tags: harmony, jazz, melody

In some jazz standards I see a final ending of `V-I` using melody tones `^3 ^1`, for example...

*Cherokee* in `B` flat

[image]

*All of Me* in `C`

[image]

Note that the `^3` in those examples is *not* some kind of embellishment of `^2` like in a cadential `6/4` or an escape tone like in these examples...

*Over the Rainbow* in `E` flat

[image]

*Autumn Leaves* in `G` minor

[image]

In the last two the `^3` can be explained as an escape tone, but in the first two there is no such embellishment.

Also, to be clear, this isn't about `^3 ^1` after arriving at a tonic chord.  The point is the `^3` coincides with the dominant chord.

I'm *not* asking about extended or "color" tones added to chords. I understand that a major sixth gets added to jazz dominants all the time.

I'm *not* asking about if it sound right, it's obviously part of the jazz style.

I'm more interested in the melodic aspect and whether there is a historic origin for this kind of ending. Perhaps this is a pattern in folk or blues melodies?

Also, I don't have or know of definitive, notated versions of `Cherokee` or `All of Me`, so I don't know if the composers originally wrote a plain dominant seventh chord in the accompaniment while the melody used `^3`. That would be interesting to know compared to the dominant chord being like an Evans, rootless type, like `7236`, where the melodic `^3` is actually present in the accompaniment chord as the `6` above the chord root. The later can be explained as a "chord tone", but the former is a sort of juxtaposing of *dominant* in the accompaniment and a *tonic* tone (`^3`) in the melody.

So, I supposed what I'm wondering is: is there a historic origin to this or was it truly a new stylistic development?

Comment: The first thing that sprang to my mind was [a seasonal example](https://youtu.be/ex0bgYffgHo)

Comment: Would a good answer be as simple as showing the earliest notated example of ^3 over a dominant?

Comment: @AndyBonner, All of Me 1931, Cherokee 1938, The Man with the Bag 1950... I'm interested in prior examples.

Comment: Hm, Scott Joplin "Pineapple Rag", 1908: check out the [second ending](https://s9.imslp.org/files/imglnks/usimg/9/96/IMSLP05473-Joplin_-_Pineapple_Rag.pdf). This could easily fall into a morass of "find all instances of cadential ^3 ^1 in history," but rag is at least close enough to argue an inherited connection. I wonder whether there are other ragtime examples? vaudeville?

Comment: @nuggethead, depends, if the context is the same as these examples, yes. If the example is 500 year old Renaissance music, so kind of evolution to jazz would be nice. Working back from jazz, blues and ragtime, then dances like foxtrot, and European waltz and march is the main line I think of. The general harmonic style of hymns pervades all of those. I'd want to see some kind of continuity over time. In other words, not one odd example that wouldn't have been an influence.

Comment: @AndyBonner, checking Pineapple Rag...  I'm not asking for all instances in history. Just some reasonable examples that might show whether it's an established thing.

Comment: @AndyBonner, in Pineapple Rag, do you mean the first second ending, second beat where the bass is `F` and the RH plays chord `Eb F A` and the melody is `C D Bb`?

Comment: Right. I notice that the overall motion there is ^1 ^2 ^3 ^1; that was true of "Somewhere Over the Rainbow" as well, and "Autumn Leaves" at least preceded the ^3 with a ^2; I wonder how often that's the case. I wonder also whether this phenomenon can be thought of as the ^3 being an "anticipated" member of the tonic chord...

Comment: That `^3` is an escape tone. I'm not looking for that, because it's really well understood. A basic analysis would label it a non chord tone. But in my example All of Me and Cherokee the point is you _can_ explain them as non chord tones.

Comment: I think important question is: are these examples really _not_ cadential V6/7, just without resolving the 6? One of characteristics of jazz is larger tolerance to the sound of upper structures. If 6 sounds less dissonant, it doesn't need to resolve. You could rewrite _All of me_ with ^3 ^2 ^1 instead of ^3 ^3 ^1 to make it sound more "classical".

Comment: @user1079505, your comment gets to the heart of my question. But these two songs were written in the 1930's before "upper structures" was a jazz thing, so I wonder if that's the best explanation. Not saying it isn't, just not sure. Especially if this happens outside of jazz.

Comment: I've always cosidered the penultimate bar in those, and many others, as V13. And how many other tunes end with 3,2,1 (as in 3 Blind Mice)?

Comment: @MichaelCurtis In _Honeysuckle Rose_, written 2 years prior to _All of Me_ the main motif ends with strong ^3 over V7, and doesn't resolve (until couple of bars later). I'm not very confident about my history knowledge, but it doesn't seem to me this kind of sound was so rare.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis consider this example from Chopin's Ballade No.2 in F major Op. 38, https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chopin-Akkord#/media/Datei:Chopin-Akkord_Ballade_F-Dur.png Chopin chords (V6/7) with ^3 moving to ^1 marked with asterisks.

Comment: I recall noticing an example of this in Monteverdi's _l'Orfeo_ when I performed it many years ago, but I don't remember exactly where -- it was many years ago.  I'll try to give it a listen and see if I can refresh my memory -- though it's obviously only of trivial interest here.  I noticed it because it reminded me of _A Shanty in Old Shantytown,_ but this form of cadence was, as you've noticed, very popular in the 1930s.

Comment: @user1079505 Honeysuckle Rose is another good example from that 1930's era, but the Chopin Ballade No. 2 is _exactly_ the kind of thing I was hoping to find. I suspected there was a historic origin. Just like tritone sub. and augmented sixth chords. And of course Chopin's influence on later song writers is obvious. If you put that in an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What a lovely question! I have never thought of that pattern, but now you mention it, I find it indeed typical of early/mid 1900's jazz melodies.

For the origins, I personally don't have much to go on, except a book of Danish traditional church music, although not by any means directly linked to any American jazz music development, but it still spans around 400 melodies from before the 15th century and up to around 1950, which I quickly siffled through, looking at melody ending patterns.

I was actually stunned to find how heavily this style relies on `^2 ^1` endings (and also often `^7 ^1`), but suddenly around the Romantic era, two or three melodies pops up with either `^3 ^1` or the more obscured `^3-(^2)^1` on the `V` chord (hope I get your melody note terminology right).

I found two melodies from 1838 and 1858 that have sort of that ending. Maybe it could be a lead into exploring what romanticism could offer in this regard. I know little of music history of this era, but I have a hunch that some small strains of romanticism of European music (from especially France and Italy I guess) may have found their way into early 1900-1920-1930's jazz styles.

The first example does not have exactly the requested ending because the style still heavily demands the `^2 ^1` ending, but the harmonization just before and at the very end feels to me to be as close as it gets to `^3 ^1` at this point in history.

[image: Dagen går med raske fjed - CEF Weyse 1838]

The second example I could find indeed has a `^2 ^3 ^1` ending but still a little concealed rythmically (as opposed to your examples where the `V` and `^3` happen simultaneously on a downbeat).

[image: Frelseren er mig en hyrde god - Chr. Barnekow 1858]